# Error with Invoke type controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, invoke

I'm having problems with and invoke type controller.
After I create the controller with php artisan make:controller -i and add the route, when go to the route it tells me that the Invoke function doesn't exist.

[image: Here is an image of the error]

Here is the route I'm using:

```
Route::get('/portfolio','PortfolioController');
```

And here is the code of the controller:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class PortfolioController extends Controller
 {
 public function __invoke(Request $request)
 {
    /** @var array $portafolio */
    $portafolio = [
        ["title" => "Proyecto #1"],
        ["title" => "Proyecto #2"],
        ["title" => "Proyecto #3"],
        ["title" => "Proyecto #4"],
    ];

    return view("portfolio", compact("portafolio"));
    }
}
```

I don't really get why this error occurs, because the invoke function is clearly there, so if anyone knows what could be the problem I will be really grateful.
I'm using the last version of Laravel.

Comment: Is this a new project?

Comment: Yes it is, I created it today. When I use the Route::view function that also uses an invoke it works, so it's really weird.

Comment: I just created another project and tried it again, and it still didn't work, so I dont know

Comment: In the latest version of Laravel for new projects you need to use `Route::get('/portfolio',PortfolioController::class);` (might need a `use` somewhere in there too)

Comment: I tried that but it still doesnt work, thanks for the response. EDIT: I forgot to import the class, now it works! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified class name as in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController;

Route::get('/portfolio', PortfolioController::class);
```